# Configure Standalone Custom Registry in Clustered WebSphere Application Server

Tags: configuration, websphere

I have a problem with configuring standalone custom registry in WebSphere Application Server (Cluster environment). I have followed all steps from IBM manual:

1. I have implemented *UserRegistry* interface in DataBaseRegistry class
2. I have copied .jar to the *lib/ext* folder of WebSphere
3. I have assigned all necessary properties on *Global Security* page

and while trying to assign Standalone Custom Registry as current I got a following error:

```
Validation failed: Error occurred in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation getUsers
```

The funny part is that I followed all of those steps in a standalone version of WebSphere (not clustered) and it is working properly (so the problem is not in the code). Another thing is that there is nothing in the log files. I can see that *getUsers* is called and then no Exception or anything.

Comment: Did you copy the .jar to the lib/ext of every WebSphere install involved? The deployment manager install as well as each application server in the cluster?

Comment: Yes I did. Actually problem was much simpler :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I resolved my problem. I was propably not 100% focused.

It tourned out that I forgot to copy additional jar with JDBC drivers to lib/ext that allow to connect to MSSQL.

LESSON LEARNED: Do not start important configuration work on Friday after lunch ;)